# External dependency on dev package vs ordinary package

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I am trying to publish a product as `apt` install. My product uses `webKit2Gtk-4.0-37` as the web rendering engine. Now while compiling my product I installed `webKit2Gtk-4.0-dev` in my machine which also installed `webKit2Gtk-4.0-37`. With the dev package I am able to compile  my product (with the normal package I am not, since my machine would not have the required header files). Now when mentioning the `depends` list for my product on the apt what will the end-user of my product need to download (as part of downloading my product), `webKit2Gtk-4.0-37` or `webKit2Gtk-4.0-dev`?

Comment: Since your finished deb package should include only the compiled binary (not the source code), the -dev package should not be needed as a dependency.

Comment: It should be a dependency for the `source` package. This is FOSS, right?

Comment: @user535733 So you mean the end-user will not have to download the -dev package as a dependency when downloading my .deb package, right? They will instead download the normal package?

Comment: @waltinator yes this FOSS, what is "it" in your statement? what do you mean by `source` package?